# Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate when signing in using authenticator form

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to implement a simple authentication UI using AWS Amplify

```
'use client'

import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import '@/configureAmplify'

export default function SignInPage() {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      Hello World
    </Authenticator>
  )
}
```

This shows a default sign in form provided by AWS.
When I try to sign in, after sign up, I get the following error

```
Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate
```

I honestly don't see what more I can do to get sign in to work.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all computer problem, rebooting the system resolved the problem.
Wonder what was the issue in the first place.